# Can you use Facebook Graph API to post a photo to a brand account as well as user account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am working on a project where a photo is taken and the user can share their photo on Facebook. We would use oAuth and the FB Graph API to post the photo and caption to the users' timeline. The client just made a request to also post it to their (the client's) photo album as well. So when the user submits a photo, it would post to the user's timeline as well as the client's timeline/album. Is this double post (to two different accounts) possible? Wouldn't that require that the client be logged in via oAuth as well? Also, are there any FB legal/regulation issues with this so long as the application has a disclaimer that it will be posted to two different places?

Answer (score 0):

The entry for the user is a new photo to the apps album for that user. me/photos

However the entry that goes to your clients page... I don't think people can do id/photos of others or pages. (it's worth a shot)

You'll have to stick to id/feed and perhaps include a link to an image host.